# Image Upload in CodeIgniter using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I have a view where the user can edit his details.

**View**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method ="post" action="<?php echo site_url('studentDashboardController/saveUserDetails');?>">
<?php echo form_open('studentDashboardController/saveUserDetails'); ?>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
<fieldset>

    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>User Details</legend>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Full Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control input-md" value="<?php foreach($details as $detail){?><?php echo $detail->name?><?php }?>">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input id="dob" name="dob" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" value="">
        </div>
    </div>

    ...

    <!-- File Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="userfile">Upload Profile Picture</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="userfile" name="userfile" class="input-file" type="file">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function  saveUserDetails()
{
    if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in']))
    {
        $uid = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['userId']);

        $data['notifyCount']=  $this->notifications->getUnreadNotification($uid);
        $data['title']=  $this->notifications->getUnreadNotificationTitle($uid);
        $data['notifyCount']=  $this->notifications->getUnreadNotification($uid);
        $data['users'] = $this->user->getUserNames();

        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/taro/profilePictures/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '10000';
        $config['max_width']  = '5000';
        $config['max_height']  = '3000';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

        $msg = $this->studentprofileModel->saveUserDetails($uid,$this->input->post());
        $msgText = $msg['msg'];
        $msgType = $msg['type'];
        //Loading View
        if($msgType == "danger")
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">'.$msgText.'</div>');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">'.$msgText.'</div>');
        }

        redirect(base_url('index.php/studentDashboardController/loadGeneralProfilePage'));
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('login/loginView');
    }
}
```

What I need to do is to first save the user details collected via the form by calling the `studentprofileModel's saveUserDetails` method. In this method I need to send the uploaded image's name so that I can store the image path in the db table's image field. And I need to upload the image to the assets folder's `subdirectory taro` as well.

I have done the following and the data from the form fields get updated in the DB. But the image file is not uploaded.

Any suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated

Comment: any error you are getting ? check uploading error by this function 
`$this->upload->display_errors());` and add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag

Comment: Your view has `<form class...` and is also calling `<?php echo form_open(...`. Isn't that giving you a `<form>` within a `<form>`?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess, before further tests, would be to add the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your `<form>` tag, as it specifies how the form-data should be encoded when submitting it to the server and the `multipart/form-data` is required when the form includes any `<input type="file">`.

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean).

---

Update 2:

Actually, it seems you may have two form tags opened? one from `<form>` and another one from `form_open()` function CI provides?
If so, use only one of them.

If you choose to do in HTML:

`<form class="form-horizontal" method ="post" action="<?php echo site_url('studentDashboardController/saveUserDetails');?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

If you choose to use CI's functions, there's two ways: `form_open` and [`form_open_multipart`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form_open_multipart) (which is exactly like `form_open` but it adds automatically the multipart thing)

`form_open('studentDashboardController/saveUserDetails', array('enctype' => "multipart/form-data"))`

or

`form_open_multipart('studentDashboardController/saveUserDetails')`

---

Update 3:

- Make sure that the folder where the image will be uploaded to have enough permissions;
- Pass the absolute path in here `$config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/taro/profilePictures/'` instead of the relative one
- Also, change this `$this->upload->do_upload();` to `$this->upload->do_upload('userfile');`

Let us know the results :)

Comment: Hi, I've added the above to the HTML code. But, I think there's something wrong in my controller. Do you mind checking that? Would be a great help.

Comment: Hi @NayantaraJeyaraj. Just updated the answer. Could you check it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code in your controller "function  saveUserDetails()"

```
   public function  saveUserDetails()
  {
      if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in']))
      {
         $uid = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['userId']);
         $post_data = $this->input->post();
       if($_FILES['image']['name'])
      {
          //load upload library
          $this->load->library('upload');

          // Specify configuration for File 
          $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/taro/profilePictures/';
          $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
          $config['max_size'] = '10000';
          $config['max_width']  = '5000';
          $config['max_height']  = '3000';
          $this->upload->initialize($config);

          if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')){
               $image_data = $this->upload->data();
              $post_data['image'] = $image_data['file_name'];
          }
          else{
              $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
         }
       }

        $msg = $this->studentprofileModel->saveUserDetails($uid,$post_data);
        $msgText = $msg['msg'];
        $msgType = $msg['type'];
        .....
   }
```

Don't forget give permision to image folder.

I hope it will work for you!!